Performing GSEA on TCGA and NES signs are flipped
New to bioinformatics, interested in kidney cancer. I'm trying to repeat the findings from a paper I like (https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-021-21068-9). They used the TCGA KIRC, TCGA KIRP, and TCGA KIRH (as well as some external data). They performed GSEA using the Hallmark gene sets (MSigDb). For simplicity sake, I've been using just TCGA KIRC downloaded from cBioPortal.
I'm doing the analysis and the results honestly look really similar, expect for the fact that my NES values are flipped (i.e. HALLMARK_MYC_TARGETS_V2 has an NES of -2.5 but in the paper its a +2.5).
I used the datafile from their paper which coded the patients with sarcomatoid.
The result is consistent, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Code below (R)
library(clusterProfiler)
library(org.Hs.eg.db)
library(fgsea)
library(DOSE)
library(msigdbr)
library(dplyr)
library(DESeq2)
library(GSVA)
library(GSEABase)
library(readxl)
library(data.table)
library (limma)
library(pheatmap)

# Step 1: obtain the sarcomatoid/non-sarcomatoid definition from Bakouny, Z, et al. 
phenotypefile <- read_excel("file.csv") # This file is the supplementary file from the paper which assigns sarcomatoid to specific TCGA samples
phenotypefile$sample_id <- gsub("\\-", ".", phenotypefile$sample_id) # Adjusts the sample_id column so that it lines up with the transcriptomic data
phenotype_kirc <- subset(phenotypefile, phenotypefile$study_id == "kirc_tcga") # removes the TCGA KIRH and TCGA KIRP

# Step 2: obtain the mRNA-seq data which is in KPM
expression_data <- read.delim("C:../kirc_tcga/data_mrna_seq_v2_rsem.txt", header = TRUE) #TCGA KIRC RNASeq data from cBioPortal
expression_data <- expression_data %>% select(-Entrez_Gene_Id) # Remove the Entrez Gene ID column
expression_data <- expression_data %>% select(-TCGA.DV.A4W0.05) # Remove the non-primary tumor sample

# Step 3: obtain the sample IDs from the column names of the expression file
sample_id <- colnames(expression_data)
sample_id <- sample_id[-c(1)] # remove the label of Hugo_Label

# There are mRNA expression data for 533 patient samples

# Step 4: Make phenotype_data with the row names corresponding to the sample IDs obtained from the expression data
phenotype_data <- data.frame(Sample_ID = sample_id)

phenotype_data <- left_join(phenotype_data, phenotype_kirc, by = c('Sample_ID' = "sample_id"))
phenotype_data <- phenotype_data %>% select(-study_id,-patient_id,-sarc_or_rhab,-rhabdoid)
phenotype_data$sarcomatoid <- phenotype_data$sarcomatoid %>%
  replace(is.na(.),0)

# There are 533 total samples. 46 of these samples are sarcomatoid. 

# Step 5: set Sample_ID as row name in phenotype_data and then remove it from the data frame
rownames(phenotype_data) <- phenotype_data$Sample_ID
phenotype_data$Sample_ID <- NULL  # Remove the Sample_ID column now that it's set as row names
phenotype_data$sarcomatoid <- as.factor(phenotype_data$sarcomatoid)

# Step 6: clean up the expression data file
# Convert to data.table
expression_data_dt <- as.data.table(expression_data)

# Aggregate any repeats by Hugo_Symbol and calculate the mean for each gene
expression_data_dt <- expression_data_dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = Hugo_Symbol]

# There were 17 Hugo_Symbol genes listed twice 

# Convert back to data.frame
expression_data <- as.data.frame(expression_data_dt)

# Remove any missing Hugo_Symbols (1 missing)
expression_data <- expression_data %>% filter(!is.na(Hugo_Symbol))

# Set row names and remove the Hugo_Symbol column
rownames(expression_data) <- expression_data$Hugo_Symbol
expression_data$Hugo_Symbol <- NULL

# Step 7: Log 2 transformation of expression data
log_expression_data <- log2(expression_data +1)
log_expression_data_matrix <- as.matrix(log_expression_data)

# Step 8: Extract the Hallmark Gene Signatures------------
hallmark_gmt_file <- "C:/.../h.all.v2024.1.Hs.symbols.gmt"
hallmark_gene_sets <- getGmt(hallmark_gmt_file)

hallmark_gene_set_list <- geneIds(hallmark_gene_sets)

# Step 9: make a named vector with the patient sample ID and sarcomatoid status -------------
sarcomatoid_status <- setNames(phenotype_data$sarcomatoid, phenotype_data$PATIENT_ID)

# Step 10: perform differential gene expression analysis ------------
t_test_results <- apply(log_expression_data, 1, function(x) {
  t.test(x ~ sarcomatoid_status)$statistic
})

# Rank genes by t-statistic (higher means more differentially expressed)
test_gene_list <- sort(t_test_results, decreasing = TRUE)

# Step 11: perform GSEA--------

# Assuming hallmark_gene_set_list is a list where names are gene set names and elements are gene vectors

# Convert list to data frame
hallmark_gene_set_df <- data.frame(
  gs_name = rep(names(hallmark_gene_set_list), times = sapply(hallmark_gene_set_list, length)),
  gene_symbol = unlist(hallmark_gene_set_list)
)

# Perform GSEA
gsea_results <- GSEA(geneList = test_gene_list, 
                     TERM2GENE = hallmark_gene_set_df,
                     pvalueCutoff = 0.05, 
                     verbose = FALSE)
# Convert results to dataframe for viewing
gsea_results_df <- as.data.frame(gsea_results)
```

